# Como usar 2 ou várias conexões no CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou fazendo um sistema onde ele pega informações de 2 bancos de dados diferentes, como posso pegar os dados e diferenciar eles no controlador e na view do CakePHP 3.x? Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tenho um exemplo aqui... Vou buscar e já posto pra você dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do seu AppController, insira as duas formas de conexão (não esqueça de manter o formato padrão do cake lá no app.php com o banco que você vai usar mais - pra facilitar sua vida né?!), depois é só fazer as conexões usando as classes

```
protected function conectarBancoCliente() {
        $configuration = [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'SEUUSERNEME',
            'password' => 'SUASENHA',
            'database' => 'SEUBANCO',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
            'log' => false,
            'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
        ];
        ConnectionManager::config('default', $configuration);

        $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');

        return $conn;
    }

protected function conectarBancoAdm() {
    $configuration = [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'SEUUSERNAME',
        'password' => 'SUASENHA',
        'database' => 'SEUBANCO',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
    ];
    ConnectionManager::config('adminitrador', $configuration);

    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('administrador');

    return $conn;
}
```